# How to get HTML element in javascript in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

**UPDATED**

I want to get value of specific html element of current tab ([url](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01F9RH0R4) )in chrome extension using Javascript. like

```
document.getElementById("productTitle").value;
```

here is my javascript code

background.js

```
function sendCurrentTitle(title) {
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.addEventListener('readystatechange', function (evt) {
    if (req.readyState === 4) {
      if (req.status === 200) {
        alert('Saved !');
      } else {
        alert("ERROR: status " + req.status);
      }
    }
  });
  req.open('POST', 'http://url/a.php', true);
  req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  req.send('url=' + title);
}

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
  
chrome.tabs.query({active: true}, function(tabs) {
      sendCurrentTitle(document.getElementById("productTitle").value);
});


});
```

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Test Extension",
  "version": "0.0",

  "background": {
    "persistent": false,
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },

"browser_action": {},

  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "tabs", 
    "<all_urls>"
  ]
}
```

I want to get product title from [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01F9RH0R4) page and send it to php api.
I am getting this error

> Error handling response: TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

Comment: Can you show the dom? `<input id="productTitle"/>` doesn't exist

Comment: I want to get the product  title from amazon https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01F9RH0R4

Comment: I just have this javascript file and one manifest file. No HTML file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your extension scripts runs in a separate window, so it cannot access DOM of other pages via its own document object. You need to specify tabs permissions in your extension manifest, and inject asome javascript into the page itself

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id,{code:   `document.getElementById("productTitle").innerText`},sendCurrentTitle);
});
```

Please not that you need to use title[0] inside sendCurrentTitle, as the callback receives an array

Comment: I am trying to get product title from https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01F9RH0R4  but it returned an "error Cannot read property 'value' of null"  please help!

Comment: Do you still get the error after implementing the changes or you're not sure how to implement them?

Comment: I have implemented the changes but still I am getting this error  (Cannot read property 'value' of null)   please have a look [here](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01F9RH0R4) am I using document.getElementById("productTitle").value) correctly for getting product title?

Comment: Could you update your post with what you've got now? Script and manifest

Comment: Ah it is a bit more complicated than I remembered! I updated my answer, please try now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225291/discussion-between-zileia-and-nadia-chibrikova).

Comment: chrome.tabs.executeScript is not a function, please help

Answer (score 0):

Best way to get DOM content is by using contentscripts
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts

Answer (score -2):

You can get an html element with query selector or DOM:-

```
document.querySelector(element);
document.getElementByID(elementID);
document.getElementByClassName(className);
```

Or you can also do this by onclick attribute:-

```
<button onclick="fun"></button>
<script>
      function(fun){
      
      }
</script>
```

Comment: I want to get element value from chrome tab not from the same html script